# Getting Values from lightning:select and lightning:input fields of dynamic form

Tags: lightning, aura

Everyone,
Looking for help on how to get the selected and input values in a Controller from a dynamic form. I can get the Name and Id of the fields, just not the values input or selected. I've tried everything I can find on stackexchange and elsewhere, to no avail. The "value" just keeps coming back undefined.

Here is my Component:

```
<aura:component controller="Accrue_FormFieldController" implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="formFields" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="formFieldOptions" type="List" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="screenId" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="formScreenId" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="val" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="ltngSelectedvalue" type="string"/>

                                        
    <!-- Use the Apex model and controller to fetch server side data -->
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--cell-buffer">
        <tbody>
            <lightning:layout>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="x-small">            
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.formFields}" var="formFields" indexVar="i" >                        
                        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">                            
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!formFields.IsPicklist__c}">                                
                            <lightning:select name="{!formFields.Name}" label="{!formFields.Name}" required="false" aura:id="{!formFields.Id}" value="{!v.val}">                
                                <option value="choose">Choose one...</option>
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.formFieldOptions}" var="formFieldOptions">                                     
                                    <aura:if isTrue="{!formFields.Id == formFieldOptions.Form_Field__c}">
                                            <option text="{!formFieldOptions.Name}" value=""></option>
                                    </aura:if>                    
                                </aura:iteration>                   
                            </lightning:select>
                                               
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <lightning:input type="{!formFields.Input_Type__c}" name="{!formFields.Name}" label="{!formFields.Name}" aura:id="{!formFields.Id}" value="{!v.val}"/>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>                 
                        </div>    
                    </aura:iteration>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save and Next" title="Save and Next" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

And my Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        // get the variable from the flow
        var screenId = component.get("v.screenId");
        //alert("screenId in Init = "+screenId);
        helper.getFormFields(component);
        helper.getFormFieldOptions(component);
        
        //component.set("v.screenId",screenId);
    },

    handleClick : function (component, event, helper) {
        var itemsList =[];
        var items = component.get("v.formFields");
        
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            var item = items[i];
            //alert('#### FieldName = '+item.Name);
            //alert('#### FieldId = '+item.Id);
            //alert('#### FieldValue = '+item.Value); //have tried everything here! it's always undefined
            
            //itemsList.push(item);
            //alert("itemsList = "+itemsList);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aura:id="{!formFields.Id}"` needs to be a hard-coded value, not an expression. The example below assumes `aura:id="formElement"`. To get the values, you can:

```
let formElements = component.find("formElement");
if(formElements) { // At least 1 element
  if(!formElements.length) { // Only one element, make Array
    formElements = [formElements];
  }
  let values = formElements.map(element => ({ key: element.get("v.name"), value: element.get("v.value") }));
}
```

You can't use `value="{!v.val}"`, because this means you're trying to put all the values in to a single variable. That would be like writing the following code:

```
let x = 5;
x = 10;
```

And expecting x to equal [5,10] or something like that. That's not how programming works in general. You could, however, have chosen to bind the value to the form element data:

```
value="{!formFields.value}"
```

Which then would allow you to use the JS you wrote (almost):

```
let items = component.get("v.formFields");
let itemsList = items.map(item => item.value);
```

Comment: @sfdxfox - that did it! thanks so kindly. 2 beers just sent. really appreciate you helping out this novice!